# SpriteKit: What's up with the coordinate system?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm teaching myself how to do SpriteKit programming by coding up a simple game that requires that I lay out a square "game field" on the left side of a landscape-oriented scene. I'm just using the stock 1024x768 view you get when creating a new SpriteKit "Game" project in XCode - nothing fancy. When I set up the game field in `didMoveToView()`, however, I'm finding the coordinate system to be a little weird. First of all, I expected I would have to place the board at (0, 0) for it to appear in the lower-left. Not so -- it turns out the game board has to be bumped up about 96 pixels in the y direction to work. So I end up with this weird code:

```
    let gameFieldOrigin = CGPoint(x:0, y:96) // ???
    let gameFieldSize = CGSize(width:560, height: 560)
    let gameField = CGRect(origin: gameFieldOrigin, size: gameFieldSize)

    gameBorder = SKShapeNode(rect: gameField)
    gameBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
    gameBorder.lineWidth = 0.1

    self.addChild(gameBorder) // "self" is the SKScene subclass GameScene
```

Furthermore, when I add a child to it (a ball that bounces inside the field), I assumed I would just use relative coordinates to place it in the center. However, I ended up having to use "absolute" coordinate and I had to offset the y-coordinate by 96 again.

Another thing I noticed is when I called `touch.locationInNode(gameBorder)`, the coordinates were again not relative to the border, and start at (0, 96) at the bottom of the border instead of (0, 0) as I would have guessed.

So what am I missing here? Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about how coordinates work?

[PS: I wanted to add the tag "SpriteKit" to this question, but I don't have enough rep. :/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reference the whole screen as a coordinate system, but you're actually setting all the things on a scene loading from **GameScene.sks**. The right way to do is modify one line in your **GameViewController.swift** in order to set your scene size same as the screen size. Initialize scene size like this instead of unarchiving from .sks file:

```
let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
```

Don't forget to remove the if-statement as well because we don't need it any more. In this way, the (0, 0) is at the lower-left corner.

To put something, e.g. `aNode`, in the center of the scene, you can set its position like:

```
aNode.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
```

Comment: I think this is putting me on the right track. Thank you!